# Uplink between switches, uplink to a server?

Tags: switch

I have two switches with 24 10/100 ports and 2 GE Uplinks. There is also a server connected to one of the switches. End users attached to both of the switches use the server's content. I assume I would like the people to get the data from server using the biggest bandwidth possible.

I can see a point in connecting two switches together to maximize the bandwidth between switches. So, I could connect two switches with a *cross* to the uplink ports on each of them.

I also know that uplinks are used to connect to the rest of the network. (I mean, a small part to a bigger part).

But apart from internal crossing on an uplink, does it differ from a regular port?
So can I also connect a server (with a gigabit ethernet port) with an uplink port of a switch?

Any comments or literature will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays there's no difference between the 10/100 ports and the gigabit ports except speed.  A lot of modern switches' "uplink" ports aren't even crossed.

We used to do the same thing - connect the file server to the gigabit port.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking it should work this way, but wanted to ensure myself.